# Correct way to take from queue?

Tags: java, concurrency

The code below randomly freezing.

The queue is pre-filled at the start and only taken from after the threads start taking items from it.

I think I'm not using the queue properly. Despite the `isEmpty()` check, the queue might be empty when one thread tries to take one item, making it to wait indefinitely.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long milisecs;
        try {
            while ( ! queue.isEmpty()) {   // !!!
                milisecs  = queue.take();  // !!!
                worker(milisecs);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    }
```

For example, it would hang is this scenario happens:

1. threadA checks if `queue.isEmpty()`, gets a false and tries to proceed.
2. threadB `take()` the last item from the queue
3. threadA tries to `take()` an item from an empty queue, making it to hang.

The process "take if queue not empty" should be synched so that the queue doesn't change in between.

What is the proper way to do that?

Full code below. Should take about 1s per run.

```
package multithreadperformance;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class MultithreadPerformance implements Runnable {
    
    static int numThreads = 50;
    static int numJobs = 5000;
    
    final BlockingQueue<Long> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();;
    static ArrayList<Thread> threads;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultithreadPerformance bench = new MultithreadPerformance();
        bench.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        System.out.print("Go... ");
        
        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        
        // Fill up the queue of jobs with a random number of miliseconds.
        long milisecs, milisecsMax = 20; // ms
        //
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) {
                milisecs = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(milisecsMax);
                queue.put(milisecs);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } 
        
        // Create all threads
        threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.setName("Thread" + i);
            threads.add(thread);
        }

        // Start all threads
        threads.forEach((thread) -> {thread.start();});

        // Join all threads
        threads.forEach((thread) -> {try {
            thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        });
        
        long et = System.nanoTime() - t0;
        System.out.println(String.format("done. Elapsed time %.3f s.", et/1e9));
    }

    // Worker function 
    // Sleep a number of miliseconds.
    public void worker(long milisecs) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(milisecs);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long milisecs;
        try {
            while ( ! queue.isEmpty()) {
                milisecs  = queue.take();
                worker(milisecs);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The take method will block until a item is available. Why dont you try the poll method with a timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `poll()` which will atomically remove the head of the queue or return `null` if the queue was empty.

```
Long millisecs;
while ( (millisecs = queue.poll()) != null) {  
     worker(millisecs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have the worker threads block on the queue. When you're done, put n End-Of-Queue messages in the queue with n the number of worker threads and have the worker threads exit their loop when they see an End-Of-Queue message.